# Can someone help me identify this bike frame?

Tags: mountain-bike, frames, identify-this-bike

I just scored this bike out of a storage unit auction. I've seen very similar frames like it before. I own a Transition Sentinel myself and my guess is that this is a Transition Scout but it has a few differences in the suspension and other subtle differences through out.Can someone help me?? The storage was kinda shady and full of alot of questionable items but totally worth the $100. This was just 1 of a few bikes from this unit. The frame is sanded down and any trace or brand names or serial numbers are grinded or sanded away. If I could get it back to the owner I would but I've spent days now trying to identify this bike accurately.

It's a GX build most likely. A TRANSITION Bike. ROCKSHOX suspension AND shocks. SRAM components. A GIANT saddle. The frame definitely looks like a Scout but the year is very important. I've compared it to all the years from 2015 to 2020 and still no exact matches. Any Transition experts or someone with a better theory or guess?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would help to narrow it down by knowing where you are. What brands are popular in your location?

Comment: Why is the year important?  Do you intend on riding this or selling it ?

Comment: Looks like the OP has bought a locker full of stolen bikes, year is the least of the OPs worries.

Comment: I intend on reselling the frame if I cannot accurately identify the bike and its owner if its assumed stolen which it probably. The year is important for that reason but if I resell, the value of the frame, if pre-2020 drastically decreases from the most current 2020 model. If I was to rebuild, the value would surely have a huge difference depending on the year. I am in Seattle WA. Transition is very popular here I think they are based out of WA. The frames shape is nearly identical to the Scout model but there are differences specifically in the joints of the suspension.

Comment: Help me bring this bike home build it back to glory!

Comment: I'd recommend you contact the local police with a list of serial numbers off the bike frames.  If nothing comes back as a match then you've done Due Diligence.   To be honest this situation is decidedly dodgy.

Comment: Can you please post a clear picture of the linkage and what the two bolts that aren't the seat stay pivot or shock mount?

Comment: Actually, hang on - if this is a light aluminum frame and someone sanded the numbers off, isn't there some risk the structural integrity is compromised?

Comment: Its a carbon frame. The sanding on either an aluminium or carbon frame wouldn't be deep enough to compromise the frame.

Answer (score 4):

I can't comment but I would if I could. Bike thieves have a tendency to sand frames down. The fact that you live in Seattle, a city with many bike thefts coupled with  the fact you got a multi thousand dollar bike for $100 points towards it being stolen. You should check local classifieds for people looking for their bike.

Comment: That's a perfectly valid answer, and an interesting point about sanding - I'd never have thought of that.

Comment: With the serial number removed there will undoubtedly be an issue around proof of ownership. It would impossible for anyone to prove definitively that the bike was theirs.

Answer (score 4):

It is a 2018 Norco Sight C2 Womens.

Here’s the link:
https://www.norco.com/bike-archives/2018/sight-c2-womens/

[image: '18 Norco Sight C2]

Comment: Great spotting!